# CSS ID WooCommerce Shop Page

Tags: css, woocommerce

Is there a CSS ID for the WooCommerce shop page like there is for single-product etc, so that I can easily target CSS for that page only?

Comment: Open you browser's developer tools and check. It would have been far faster than posting your question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WooCommerce does not add a body class specifically for the main shop page.
`post-type-archive-product` is probably enough for most cases.

But if you want to specifically style the main shop page instead of all product archives then you can use a filter:

```
add_filter('body_class', 'add_my_woocommerce_shop_body_class');
function add_my_woocommerce_shop_body_class($classes)
{
    if (is_shop()) {
        $classes[] = 'my-woocommerce-shop-class';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check for classes in body tag of your shop page. If your theme adds any specific class for shop then you'll find it there else `post-type-archive-product` class may help.